# react-native prop type for text style

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

i have component with a simple structure and a `<Text>` somewhere inside the tree for which i want to pass in a style. Which works perfectly but for the proptypes validation.

The basic setup is not much more than that

```
export default class Component extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (<View><Text style={this.props.style}>Some text</Text></view>);
    }
}

Component.defaultProps = {
    style: null,
};

Component.propTypes = {
    style: ViewPropTypes.style,
};
```

The problem is that the ViewPropTypes.style does not contain i.e. `color` key. So providing a style with a color is invalid and produces a warning. I tried to import `TextStylePropTypes` as i found in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Text/TextStylePropTypes.js but it is undefined.

Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 27):

For anybody trying to achieve this seems like `View.propTypes.style` is deprecated while `Text.propTypes.style` is not.

Comment: For view style prop check `import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';` & `style: ViewPropTypes.style,` use this

Comment: As of React Native 0.62, Text.propTypes.style is also deprecated.

Comment: @EricWiener, have you found the solution for this error in 0.62 version? because i am finding the same error.

Comment: @EricWiener i have remove all these thing from everywhere but there is no any success.

Comment: @anshumanburmman Make sure there aren't any occurrences in any of your dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

As the passed style prop is for the Text node, use `Text.propTypes.style` as shown below...

```
Component.propTypes = {
    style: Text.propTypes.style
};
```