# How to properly type style props for Text with React Native PropTypes and ESLint

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to use `styles: Text.propTypes.style` as proposed in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565754/react-native-prop-type-for-text-style).

But ESlint is complaining:

`` ESLint: Using `propTypes` from another component is not safe because they may be removed in production builds (react/forbid-foreign-prop-types) ``

What is the right way to solve this?